# Google API Key for every possible App

Tags: api, google-maps, titanium, sha, android-keystore

So i'm building an app on appcelerator that uses Google Maps API to show some information on Maps (for android).. I've read all the tutorials, and instructions from Google Developers Console about requesting an API Key. As far as I know, an API Key depends on a SHA1 Fingerprint of the keystore you're using to test your app. That's just fine, I got my API Key and everything works on my Development environment.

The problem is that my boss, at the moment of testing, can't get to see the maps, I think cause his "dev_keystore" SHA1 defers from mine, so there must be an Authentication problem. (that i know right)

But what bothers me the most is that there is another app that he (or someone on his team) builded, I get that app to my development environment, runs it with his API Key, and it works... even using my dev_keystore i guess...

So my question is: is it possible to create an API Key that works on every environment, regarthless the key_store SHA1 and stuffs ? I mean, how in hell is that API Key configured that works fine on my computer, as well as in his.?

Comment: Most environments have a debug keystore that gets defaulted to. Create a separate release keystore file and then it should work on other environments. Docs: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Yeah, I also know that in order to distribute my app (release mode) I should provide a Signature and stuff... but we've not come to that yet. The app taht was shared to me has no release keystore file. I just got the code, compiled it in my environment (with their Google API Key in Tiapp.xml) an it worked right away. I did not setup signature files nor any other configuration.

Comment: This also seems to be true: "  Tip: If you decide, for example, to use the debug certificate at first and then the release certificate, you will need to obtain a separate API key for the release certificate- just follow the same process with the SHA-1 fingerprint for your release certificate when you are ready  ".

Comment: Another idea comes to my mind: Is it possible that Titanium Studio debug keystore file is the same for every instance of Titanium Studio ? if that's true, my best guess is that the others developers created an API Key for that SHA1 (that's supposed to be the same for every environment), and that API Key is the one that's working for me right ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i figured out what's going on.. The default keystore that comes with titanium studio is the same for every installment of it. So the other developers might have (and the did) created an API Key for those apps with the default keystore, and that's why it is working on every environment.

I bet that when my boss tries to publish that app, it will not work at all. he'll need to create a more app-related API Key, but that's another story to tell.

Comment: In case you're asking what tha SHA1 is: CC:E3:7F:08:FA:03:9C:88:07:BC:CB:AB:7B:88:61:F4:75:9D:47:9F;your.package.name